# What does the `-context` parameter mean when using FFV1 in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

In the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/~michael/ffv1.html) for FFV1 there's a parameter `-context`, which can be set to 'small' or 'large'. That's all the documentation I can find.

[image]

While I'm at it, what are the relative benefits of the different encoders: Golomb Rice vs Range Coder?

Answer (score 2):

The coder here refers to the process used for [entropy coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_encoding) the error residuals. The context size sets how many neighbouring residuals are considered in this process.

As to the relative benefits, have no particular experience here, but since this is a lossless process, the tradeoff will be between time, size and resource use. This latter question is better suited for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

About your other question regarding the `-coder` option, I was also looking for more info on this.

The current (Dec. 2020) IETF/cellar WG draft "[FFV1 Video Coding Format Version 0, 1, and 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-cellar-ffv1/)" mentions in it's "[4.2.3. coder_type](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-cellar-ffv1-19.html#name-coder_type)" chapter :

> Restrictions:
>
> If coder_type is 0, then bits_per_raw_sample SHOULD NOT be > 8.
>
> Background:
>
> At the time of this writing, there is no known implementation of FFV1 bitstream supporting Golomb Rice algorithm with
> bits_per_raw_sample greater than 8, and Range Coder is prefered.

So without understanding much about it, I just concluded : "always use `-coder 1`" ... :-)